# Prepopulating a form Select field in django with specific values and initializing it

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model in django that has a foreign key to the django user model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and a corresponding model form

```
class EntryForm(ModelForm)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

The user field uses a Select widget. I want this widget to only have staff users. So I tried the following.

Ιn the view:

```
form = EntryForm(initial={'user':User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)}
```

but didn't work. The Select widget shows all users staff and non-staff

Then i tried this:
    form = EntryForm()
    form.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff = True)

and worked. 
What i want to do is narrow the options of the select user to staff only users but I want to be able to have pre-selected a certain value, e.g the user logged in(staff user).e.g

```
form = EntryForm(initial={'user':request.user}) #pre-select specific user
form.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff = True) #only show staff users
```

but this doesn't work. Let me say here that i want to initialize other form fields too e.g date and other, but i have left them out for simplicity.

I also tried using the **init** method of form, but won't work well with the above code

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

gives me an error(used pass for testing purposes).

```
AttributeError
    'EntryAddForm' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

So is there a way to do initialize a Select field in a form and also exclude or include a certain queryset at the same time in that field?

Answer (score 1):

I think I sovled it..What I did was

```
form = EntryForm()
form.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
form.fields['user'].initial = request.user
```

And worked. I should put all form logic like this in the **init** right?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a shot in the dark, but your `EntryForm.Meta` class seems to need a `fields` attribute, as explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

```
class EntryForm(ModelForm)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ["user"]
```

Comment: I added the link to the corresponding Django documentation.

Comment: Wierd...In the 1.5ver docs which i am using there is no need for fields. And there isn't cause it works fine. I just added the what i needed to the __init__ method. Also the problem was i wasn't calling super (stupid me!!!). But that field meta property is strange.